# Ajax callback always returning error ASP.NET Web Service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

When I try to debug method on webservice the callback returns error, I tried to debug the error, and the textStatus is just "error", I tried to debug with fiddler and the answer is returning OK(200) and I don't know why when I debug it fails and when I don't debug it works properly.

ClientSide:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WBSJsonRequests.asmx/InsertInterConsulta",
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (JsonResponseData) {

                if (JsonResponseData.d === "success") {
                    alert("Se han agregado la esta especialidad correctamente!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Se ha producido un error en el servidor: " + JsonResponseData.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log(textStatus);

                alert(textStatus);
            }

        });
```

WebService.asmx:

```
  <WebMethod(Description:="Inserta Interconsulta")> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function InsertInterConsulta(InterConsultaList As InterConsulta, IdCita As Integer) As String
    Dim Searializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Try


        InterConsultaList.IdCita = IdCita
        Meds.InterConsulta.GuardarInterConsulta(InterConsultaList.IdEspecialidad, InterConsultaList.IdCita)


        Return "success"


    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message

    End Try

End Function
```

If I set a breakpoint and try to debug pressing (F10) it is returning before the method finished with error, if I don't do that it workds fine, it looks like a time out, I guess that if you use your method async it has a specific time to wait and if it doesn't get a response then it goes back, but If it'd be a timeout I guess textStatus would say "timeout" instead of error so I want to know what is going on.

Anothing detail is that if I use "async: false", everything works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try F11 instead.

Comment: Yes I did and it still did the same thing